# Common solutions to 3SAT and 2SAT models comprised of the same variables

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, 2sat

I have a problem which is a combination of 3SAT & 2SAT instances.
Consider $L$ is a set of variables $(x_1 ... x_n)$. $S_3(L)$ is a 3-SAT instance and $S_2(L)$ is a 2SAT instance, both made of variables in L.
The actual boolean formula to solve is $B = S_3(L) \wedge S_2(L)$. So the solution for B is an intersection of the solution sets of $S_3(L)$ and $S_2(L)$.

Both $S_3$ and $S_2$ can be solved separately, and then we can select a common solution to solve B. I was wondering if I can use the 2SAT solution to more efficiently solve the 3SAT instance, for e.g. can I use the implication graph from the solution of the 2SAT instance to guide the search for solution to the 3SAT instance?

I am aware we build an implication graph when solving a 3SAT instance through DPLL. So can we use an existing graph to guide the DPLL solver?

*Edited to better (hopefully) specify the problem*

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking.  You say "the solution to the 2SAT instance".  Is there a unique solution to the 2SAT instance?  If so, the question is trivial: just use that solution.  If not, the question is trivial: in the worst case it doesn't help.  Also, the next sentence seems to contradict the previous sentence.  Please edit the question to clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide better clarity.

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer?  As @D.W. points out, in the worst case the problem is as hard as 3-SAT, so NP-hard.  Are you looking for heuristics?  Are you wondering whether there is existing work on SAT solvers that might apply?  Or maybe on average-case analysis of SAT?  Also, what is "the DPLL solver"?

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you cannot.  If $S_2(L) = (x_1 \lor \neg x_1)$, say, then the implication graph for $S_2(L)$ gives you no information on the solutions to $S_3(L)$ or $B$.

If you want to know how to solve it in practice, throw $B$ into a SAT solver.  No need to distinguish between the two types of clauses: SAT solvers already do everything there is to do.

Comment: I am actually working on writing my own SAT solver and was wondering if I can use this form of the SAT problem as a "accelerator" to speed it up since I think I can transform any 3SAT problem into such a conjunction. I know that in the worst case the problem is still NP-hard so it is not useful for all cases, but I am wondering if it can still be useful in some cases. I am trying to code this up and if I can, I will profile and post my results.

Comment: The propagator of any modern SAT solver already fully utilizes binary implications.